# Android changeable background image

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Java. I have some background image view. Here is my code:

```
mBackgroundImage = (Imageview) findViewById(R.id.image);
mBackgroundImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageBG);`
```

How to make imageBG changeable from settings? I'm working on `systemUI.apk`, and I want to change the image background from image picker on my `settings.apk`.

Comment: What are you trying to tell with the word "setting"? If you are not able to tell provide your question as image or explain more.

Comment: hope you understand now :)

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. In your code snip, you show setting a background from a resource. That looks basically correct. If you have a question on how to use an image picker, then provide code and specific questions for that and we can help you.

Comment: how to setImageresource from uri?